# How to detect 'current week' for render days conditionally?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I discovered the dayRender function today (in the `v4.0.0beta4` of `fullCalendar.io`).

My goal is render the previous weeks with gray background, the current week with white background e the future weeks with a third backgroundcolor.

Is there something in fullcalendar.io objects that can help me?

Using

```
dayRender: function(dayRenderInfo) { 
    console.log(  $(dayRenderInfo.el).data('date') );
    return dayRenderInfo.el;
}
```

I know that `dayRenderInfo` contains `el`, so using jQuery I can read `$(el).data('date')` to retrieve the date of the rendered day 'cell'.

But then, in js, how to check it, for example '2019-03-20' is the current week or past or future ?

I posted the question using fullcalendar tag because I hope there is an helper proprerty or similar, otherwiser, anyway, a plain js solution is very appreciated.

Comment: You could parse the date as a datetime object or momentJS object and then compare it easily to the current date. And with moment it's not too hard to find out the start and end of the current week as well. P.s. fullCalendar 4 is now fully released, no need to use the beta. And it doesn't use jQuery any more, although I guess there's nothing stopping you still utilising it for other things in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is use the `dayRender` function of `fullCalendar.io` (actually @`v4.0.1`)

The function receive an HTML element already rendered. But you can intercept and manipulate it.

I decided to append an attribute, `data-date`, to the element so I can check it at runtime.

Note: I'm using jQuery.

```
dayRender: function(dayRenderInfo) { 

    // Make a Date object from current rendered element
    const day = dayRenderInfo.el;
    const date_str_of_this_day = $(day).data('date');
    const this_day = new Date(date_str_of_this_day);

    const today_string = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);        

    // 0 (Sunday) ... 6 (Saturday)
    let number_of_weekday = this_day.getDay();
    if (number_of_weekday ==0) {
        // I shift to adapt to italian week
        // 1 (Monday) ... 7 (Sunday)
        number_of_weekday = 7;
    }

    // From today's date object, I can find monday
    let first = this_day.getDate() - number_of_weekday + 1;
    const monday_date = new Date(this_day.setDate(first));
    const monday_string = monday_date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    // From monday's date object I can find sunday
    let last = monday_date.getDate() + 6;
    const sunday_date = new Date(this_day.setDate(last));
    const sunday_string = sunday_date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    if (sunday_string < today ) {

         // the current day being renderer is AFTER current week
         dayRenderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor =   '#ededed';
    } else if (today < monday_string ) {

        // the current day being renderer is BEFORE current week
        dayRenderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor =   '#f9e9d7';
    } else {

        // the current day being renderer is PART OF curremt week
        dayRenderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor =   'white';
    }

    // return altered html rendered
    return dayRenderInfo.el;
},
```